# How install Solr on mac using homebrew?

Tags: macos, solr, osx-mavericks, homebrew

In my homebrew I have access only to solr 4.9.0, but it was deleted from repo, so I see 404 error:

```
bmalets:~ bmalets$ brew install solr
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=lucene/solr/4.9.0/solr-4.9.0.tgz
==> Best Mirror http://apache.ip-connect.vn.ua/lucene/solr/4.9.0/solr-4.9.0.tgz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "solr"
Download failed: http://apache.ip-connect.vn.ua/lucene/solr/4.9.0/solr-4.9.0.tgz
```

Now solr 4.10.0 version are already avialable, but brew don't see it...
Because in every turtorial for solr I see 'at 1st - run `brew install solr`'.
And I don't want to have a problems with updating/upgrading in future...
How can I setup brew to install fresh Solr version on my mac?

p.s. Homebrew 0.9.5, OS_X 10.9.5

Comment: i propose you to just download it from http://lucene.apache.org/solr/, cause solr doesn't require a lot of installation and you don't need to depends on some system

Comment: but how fix homebrew problem?

Comment: have no idea. i'm not specialist with homebrew

Comment: This is working again now perfectly fine. Solr installs from a mirror automatically if the first link doesn't work. I just installed 7.2 and worked fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- run `brew edit solr` to edit solr formula
- replace old formula for version 4.9.0 with [formula for v4.10.0](https://github.com/KDAB/Homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/solr.rb)
- run `brew install solr`
- run `solr start`

Answer (score 37):

Running

```
brew update
```

and then

```
brew install solr
```

fixed this error for me

Comment: Indeed, 404 error is fixed now. `brew install solr` fetches the latest version without any hiccups

Answer (score 3):

Updating homebrew did not do the trick for me. Homebrew updated its Solr formula to Solr 4.9 but the URL is no longer valid.

I fixed this issue by editing the Solr formula:

`brew edit solr`

and changing the URL to:
url 'http://www.eng.lsu.edu/mirrors/apache/lucene/solr/4.10.2/solr-4.10.2.tgz'

and changing the sha1 checksum to:
b913204d07212d7bb814afe4641992f22404a27d

then you'll be able to run

`brew install solr`

without issues.

*If the URL I provided above is no longer valid in the future, you can update your Solr formula to any of the tgz sources found here: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/4.10.2
and then update the `sha1` checksum in the formula to the sha1 checksum of the tgz file you decide to use. (http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201259)*

Answer (score 2):

Simple Steps:

1) brew update

2) brew Install solr

3) Restart the terminal/cmd

4) For Background run - brew services start solr

5) for just starting - start solr