# Downgrade SOLR to V8 using homebrew on mac

Tags: solr, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Brew has updated me to version 9 of SOLR which doesn't work for me and is different to all of the sites I work on remotely, I need to get back to version 8 but I am unsure of how to go about this?

**I have tried various parts of these without any success:**

- [How to install solr 6.x with Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833180/how-to-install-solr-6-x-with-homebrew)
- [How install Solr on mac using homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995113/how-install-solr-on-mac-using-homebrew)

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3987683/3001761? There's a v8 formula too: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/solr@8.11.  Not sure this is really a programming question.

Comment: Thanks that didn't seem to work but then I tried a restart and it seems to be on 8.11 now! Sorry if this isn't programming I thought seeing as there were similar questions here that asking this here was acceptable? Anyway thanks for your help much appreciated.